# asp not showing variable values

Tags: asp-classic

In my index.asp file I have the following code:

```
    <input name="inf_custom_Referrer" type="hidden" value="<%=response.write(request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER"))%>" />
    <input name="inf_custom_IPAddress" type="hidden" value="<%=response.write(request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR"))%>" />
```

When I view the source in chrome, this is what is shown:

```
    <input name="inf_custom_Referrer" type="hidden" value="<%=response.write(request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER"))%>" />
    <input name="inf_custom_IPAddress" type="hidden" value="<%=response.write(request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR"))%>" />
```

Why is it not writing the values properly?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
<input name="inf_custom_Referrer" type="hidden" value="<%=response.write(request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER"))%>" />
<input name="inf_custom_IPAddress" type="hidden" value="<%=response.write(request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR"))%>" />
```

To this

```
<input name="inf_custom_Referrer" type="hidden" value="<%=request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER")%>" />
<input name="inf_custom_IPAddress" type="hidden" value="<%=request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")%>" />
```

In ASP Classic response.write can be abbreviated, for example;

```
<% response.write myVariable %>
```

Can be also be coded

```
<%=myVariable%>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%=x%>` and `<%response.write(x)%>` are the same .

pick any ONE only.